# WebDriver- Handle HTML Pop-Up

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am Trying to get past the Window just above the Login Page 
Note since html Class names are dynamic, I am Not Holding them in my xpath

WebSite --> seatseller.travel //
Objective --> 
Click the Cancel button of the Offer page (It only shows ONCE and saves in Local Storage of Browser as Property)
Note : since html Class names are dynamic, I am Not Holding them in my xpath

I have tried all viable solutions as 1) Trying to Hold Frames ;  2) Trying it as Alert failed..

Any Working solution will be a Gift

Thanks in Advance

public class dhmaka {

```
    /**
     * @param args
     * @throws InterruptedException 
     * @throws IOException 
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, IOException {



        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://in3.seatseller.travel/");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
         // Exit Summer Dhamaka Frame ..
        String currentWindow = driver.getWindowHandle();

        Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
        Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
        String subWindowHandler = null;
        while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);             
        System.out.println(subWindowHandler);
        driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);                 
        driver.findElement(By.name("//div[@class = 'popupContent']/div/div[2]")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.close();
    }
```

}

Comment: is that By.name or By.Xpath?

Comment: My Bad ... It worked .. such a Silly thing OfCourse its a Xpath...and not Name

Comment: Thanks.. It happens.. :) Added my answer below and accept that as the correct response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `By.XPath()` instead of `By.name()` as what you have given is actually XPATH.

That should work.